# Conformal field theory using Mathematica

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, software

Can someone suggest some online Mathematica codes/packages that deal with performing standard CFT computations like OPE expansions, computing different conformal blocks etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic [because it's a software recommendation](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/should-we-allow-software-questions-take-3) and does not seem to meet the standards in [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9912/allowance-of-computational-physics-questions) that might qualify it to be considered differently.

Comment: @DavidZ, besides the fact that this question is generally of low quality, what is wrong with the topic? I am not sure how the links you provided have any relevance to this question. The first one actually cites [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/should-we-allow-software-questions-take-2) which suggests that software which is _only_ relevant to physicists is on-topic. And obviously nobody outside of physics cares (and would know) about tools for computations in CFTs.

Comment: Relevant to the question, the OP should at least clarify what kind of CFT (2d/higher-d) they are talking about.

Comment: If the question is off-topic please let me know which forum (of stack exchange, say) I should ask this question to. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterKravchuk (3 comments up) The first one I linked is newer than the one you linked, and in the absence of a [meta-tag:faq] on the topic, I'll go by the newest one. That seems to indicate that we've chosen to make software recommendations off topic.

Comment: @DavidZ, the one you linked contains approximately zero discussion, so it seems a bit weird to apply it as a policy. But whatever, I'm not the moderator here.

Answer (score 4):

**Conformal Bootstrap**

A [page by an associate professor](http://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/Mathematica/) at Brandeis University has provided a notebook to implement the Virasoro algebra in *Mathematica*, and compute conformal blocks. It can also teach *Mathematica* other operator algebras.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05552) also provides ancillary files which include notebooks that can be used to compute conformal blocks using an alternate method built upon in the paper.

**Operator Product Expansion**

A [*Mathematica* package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/9674/) provides a means to compute crossing matrices and OPEs for special cases involving degenerate operators.

Finally, a package called [Lambda](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5264) has been designed to calculate $\lambda$-brackets, which can be related directly to show they are equivalent to evaluating OPEs for $d=2$ CFTs.

A bunch of files [here](http://msstp.org/?q=node/286) and elsewhere on the site of the *Mathematica* summer school provides exercises and *Mathematica* notebooks which involve applying the conformal bootstrap. This includes the decomposition of conformal blocks and working in $d=4-\epsilon$ dimensions.